# Vite Build Problem During Gitlab Docker Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, vite

I have a very simple GitLab pipeline:

```
stages:  
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

composer:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
    paths:
      - vendor/
  
  script:
      - composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts      
      - php artisan config:cache      
      - php artisan route:cache
      - php artisan view:cache      
      - php artisan ziggy:generate
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - ${ENV_FILE}

npm:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build      
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 hours
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/css/
      - public/js/
```

I tested the single job steps locally, and it works. However, on the GitLab server, with docker runner, it fails the npm job with this error:

```
[vite:load-fallback] Could not load vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js (imported by resources/js/app.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'
error during build:
Error: Could not load vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js (imported by resources/js/app.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I checked the artifacts from the composer step, and the ziggy folder is in the vendor folder, indeed. Cache problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `npm` job requires artifacts that are created and stored as part of the `composer` job. However, since both these jobs are in the same stage (`build`), they run at the same time. So the `composer` job will kick off the same time as `npm` starts running, so the `vendor` directory doesn't and will never exist.

You can fix this however by simply placing any job that requires the artifacts from an earlier job in a separate stage:

```yaml
stages:
  - build_composer
  - build_npm
  - test
  - deploy

composer:
  stage: build_composer
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
    paths:
      - vendor/
  
  script:
      - composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts      
      - php artisan config:cache      
      - php artisan route:cache
      - php artisan view:cache      
      - php artisan ziggy:generate
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - ${ENV_FILE}

npm:
  stage: build_npm
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build      
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 hours
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/css/
      - public/js/
```

Comment: yes you are totally right! I missed the fact that in Gitlab job are isolated!. Thank you.